# iOS Map : Extracting all of the roads from an area

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview, mapkit

Real random question.

I was playing Friendly Fire, and it allows you to pick your current location on a map and then it turns that in to game data. It turns all the roads in to in game roads which you can then build buildings next to.

Last time I looked at MKMapKit I did not see a way of doing this.  Any ideas.

Comment: Perhaps they are using OpenStreetMap, which does allow direct access to data like this?

Comment: Is it fairly easy to extract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Overpass API with the XAPI compatibility layer for getting data from the OpenStreetMap database with RESTful requests.

The full documentation is here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/XAPI_Compatibility_Layer

To get all the roads in a bounding box, your request URL would look like this:

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?way[bbox=7.1,51.2,7.2,51.3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, if anyone has a basic demo that would rock!

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly extract MapKit's data, but you could use a combo of something like OpenStreetMap data and the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) to get MapKit-like behavior but with a correlation between the UI and the extractable data.